# How to push a new branch to remote git with commit message

Tags: git, github

My remote git server does not allow me to push anything without having a commit message.
Now i want to convert my perforce code to git using `git p4` and push the converted code as a new branch to my remote git server. When i do `git push origin mybranch` it is failing as there is not commit that i did using `git commit -a` or `git commit -m` . How i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add (or update) a README file in your new branch, then commit with a comment.  At that point, you should be able to push the new branch. Providing some detail in the README about the origin of the code (in P4) may be useful if future pulls/pushes/merges to/from the external repo are needed.